# How to change post to page

Tags: posts, pages

If I have to change a number of posts to pages, does this require anything more complex that setting the post-type to page on the table wp_posts? Do any other settings need to be changed.

Is it better to use a plugin like Convert Post Types or Vice Versa instead? I have a number of posts that I like being able to categorize on a site, but I may need to change to pages in the future.

Thanks,

Comment: Do I need to be concerned with any other settings or tables? I expect I would lose my tagging, but I want to make sure there is not some other table that tracks post properties differently than page properties.

Comment: No, you don't need to be concerned by that.  You're not going to "lose" your tagging, but because WordPress doesn't recognize tags as a taxonomy assigned to posts, you won't be able to access them with out some addition code.  Any post type can have a taxonomy (categories, tags), you just have to assign that taxonomy to it via http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Its Possible Just Simply Run This Query Once 
If You're Not Developer Then Don't to Anything 
Just Simply log in to your cpanel->open phpmyadmin->There is maybe one or more database you've to find which one is wordpress database (click on database and where all table names starts with "wp_" its your Wordpress Database -> and check there's few tab "browse / structure /SQL" Go to SQL Paste this Code write below and click on go you're done now.

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_type`='page' WHERE `post_type`='post'
```

Comment: I asked a similar question here, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/206483/can-i-change-a-post-to-a-page-by-changing-its-type but I'm doing this in PHP. Hoping it's as simple as changing the value.

Answer (score 0):

As Mohit Bumb said, you can change the post type without fear.  Changing the SQL entry in `wp_posts` `post_type` to *page* or *post* will be enough. There are a few options listed below.

### Run an SQL Query to Change All *Posts* to *Pages*

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_type`='page' WHERE `post_type`='post'
```

Note: `wp_posts` could have a unique string between wp_ and _posts. Use yours.

1. Open PhpMyAdmin.

   - Follow your hosting providers instructions to log into PhpMyAdmin.
2. Look for and click on your WordPress database in the left column. The correct database should have table names starting with "wp_".
3. On the top tabs labeled "... Structure, SQL..." Click the SQL tab.
4. Paste the code above and click on the "Go" button to change **ALL** *posts* in your database to *pages*.
5. Done; all posts will be pages.

   *Note: `wp_posts` could have a unique string between `wp_??????_posts`. Use yours.*

### Single *Post* Modification with PhpMyAdmin

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type`='post' AND `post_status`!='trash'
```

1. Follow steps 1 - 3 above.
2. Paste the code above and click on the "Go" button to view all posts from your blog.
3. Find the post you want to change by its `post_title` or other column you choose and select the edit button.
4. Scroll down to `post_type` and change the text to *page*
5. Press the "Go" button to change this *post* to a *page*.
6. Done; find your page in WP page category.

   *Note: `wp_posts` could have a unique string between `wp_??????_posts`. Use yours.*

### Plugin Method

You could use a plugin, such as Post Type Switcher, and perhaps remove it when done.