# Can I change a post to a page by changing it's type?

Tags: posts, pages

I'm looking at the properties of the `$post` object and there is a `type` property. In the code if, I write it out it says, `post`. If I change this to `page` will it show up as a page? I can try it but I don't want to break anything and usually in my experience there is more to it, for example, a separate table or something.

The reason I want to change it is because it looks like I can only select a *page* as the front page alternative. I've done some custom work and all my work is with posts, not pages.

I've found this but it's a database query:

[How to change post to page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27476/how-to-change-post-to-page?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `post_type` property of a post is easy, but there are a few con's you would need to consider here before doing so

- Non hierarchical post types (like `post`) behaves way different that hierarchical post types (like `page`). I'm not going to explain everything here, but in general, most importantly, non hierarchical post types have taxonomies bound to it, while hierarchical post types have parent-child relationships. There are still a lot of diffences like templates, post type supports, etc

  Changing a `post` to a `page` stuffs this whole relationship and setup
- Even when just changing any non hierarchical post type to another non hierarchical (*or hierarchical to another hierarchical post type*), you can run into issues. Again look at bullet point one.

In short, you should really avoid blindly changing the post type of any post (*specially from hierarchical to non hierarchical and vice versa*). You need to make very sure of your structures and how it would be affected should you change the post type of a post.

Comment: Should I create pages then instead of post for the front page? Can the front page show the loop?

Comment: Yes, you should definitly do that. A static front page needs to be a page as it needs a page template. Use a custom query on the front page.

Comment: Is there a way to use the standard loop with a page? I need a page or a post that can show the loop and then be able to point to that when someone comes to the website. I'm storing custom data in the custom fields and if I can get that data I can probably keep the front page the way it is and pull that data into it.

Comment: I will post an answer to your other question ;-)

Comment: I've decided to create pages instead of posts. Can I create a page simply by setting the type to page?

Comment: You can do that, but there might be one or two extra small things you will need to sort out, although this should work out of the box. You might need to flush rewrites after the change, which in any case will be a very good idea

Comment: With "page" types can the page have a parent page?